# New query executer in Jaspersoft Studio for DeployR

Tags: r, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I am trying to combine Jaspersoft Studio with DeployR script. I am using this tutorial from Microsoft [here](https://deployr.revolutionanalytics.com/documents/dev/integrate-jasper/#upload) which is in fact for iReport (the former solution of Jaspersoft Studio). I have added the necessary jar files as in tutorial to the class path, and deployed the R script in DeployR.

After running the report in Jasper there comes nothing on the report with no errors given. But I have a warning which says:  `No query executer factory class registered for deployrScript queries.` So I guess the problem is that Jaspersoft Studio can not find the class for deployrScript, although this class `jRQueryExecuter2` is in the class path!

In jrxml you can see the declaration:

```
    <queryString language="deployrScript">
        <![CDATA[<deployr url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/deployr">
           <script filename="Cluster_Demo_Jasperserver.R" directory="root"  author="testuser"/>
        </deployr>]]>
    </queryString>
```

The whole jrxml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="deployrSample" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5a314889-9cd2-4943-ad5f-13ef1bd6ca74">
    <parameter name="RRP_plotwidth" class="java.lang.Double" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[555]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="RRP_plotheight" class="java.lang.Double" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[555]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="RRP_dataset" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["iris"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="RRP_clusters" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[3]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="RRP_clustering_type" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["hclust"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="deployrScript">
        <![CDATA[<deployr url="http://127.0.0.1:8000/deployr">
    <script filename="Cluster_Demo_Jasperserver.R" directory="root" author="testuser"/>
</deployr>]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="REPORT1" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[file:cluster_output.png]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="63" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="30" y="10" width="50" height="37" uuid="4ce16c2b-5680-48b6-86e8-ce992c543a40"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["C:/Users/aort.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="600" splitType="Stretch">
            <image scaleImage="RetainShape" hAlign="Center">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="100" y="40" width="353" height="218" uuid="f2294c37-5751-41f9-a3b4-fcfe80b69fec"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{REPORT1}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

and the R script:

```
library(cluster)

#uncomment these lines to test in standalone mode
dataset <- "mtcars"
clusters <- 4
clustering_type <- 'hclust'
plotwidth<-555
plotheight<-555


if (dataset == 'iris') {
  data <- iris[,1:4]
  df <-data.frame(data$Sepal.Length, data$Sepal.Width)

} else if (dataset == 'mtcars') {
  data <- mtcars
  df <-data.frame(data$drat, data$disp)
} else {
  stop("Enter a valid dataset")
}

if (clustering_type == 'kmeans') {

  fit <- kmeans(df, clusters)
  png("cluster_output.png", width=plotwidth, height=plotheight);
  clusplot(df, fit$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE, labels=0, lines=0, main = dataset)
  dev.off()

} else if (clustering_type == "hclust") {

  d <- dist(as.matrix(df))
  fit <-hclust(d)
  png("cluster_output.png", width=plotwidth, height=plotheight);
  plot(fit, main = dataset)
  dev.off()

} else  {
  stop ("enter a valid clustering type")
}
```

The DeployR code:

```
library(cluster)

#uncomment these lines to test in standalone mode
#dataset <- "iris"
#clusters <- 4
#clustering_type <- 'hclust'
#plotwidth<-555
#plotheight<-555
if (dataset == 'iris') {
  data <- iris[,1:4]
  df <-data.frame(data$Sepal.Length, data$Sepal.Width)

} else if (dataset == 'mtcars') {


data <- mtcars
  df <-data.frame(data$drat, data$disp)
} else {
  stop("Enter a valid dataset")
}

if (clustering_type == 'kmeans') {

  fit <- kmeans(df, clusters)
  png("cluster_output.png", width=plotwidth, height=plotheight);
  clusplot(df, fit$cluster, color=TRUE, shade=TRUE, labels=0, lines=0, main = dataset)
  dev.off()

} else if (clustering_type == "hclust") {

  d <- dist(as.matrix(df))
  fit <-hclust(d)
  png("cluster_output.png", width=plotwidth, height=plotheight);
  plot(fit, main = dataset)
  dev.off()

} else  {
  stop ("enter a valid clustering type")
}
```

I have added `net.sf.jasperreports.query.executer.factory.deployrScript=com.revo.deployr.client.jasper.factory.RQueryExecuterFactory` to properties as suggested by Narcis, but still the REPORT1 field is empty and I get nothing in report.
My question is how can I add DeployR to Jaspersoft Studio?

Comment: Did you check the same report in iReport?

Comment: No, I am using only jaspersoft Studio

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you have followed does not seem to go into details on how to register the query executer(point #9 in the **DeployR Custom Client Library** section).

Besides adding the jar files to the classpath, you also need to set properties like this one in Jaspersoft Studio:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.query.executer.factory.[your_query_language_name]=[the_canonical_name_of_your_query_executer_factory_class]
```

In your case you should have:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.query.executer.factory.deployrScript=com.revo.deployr.client.jasper.factory.RQueryExecuterFactory
```

If you plan to use this on a JasperReports Server instance, you need to set the same property for the webapp in the `<webapp-path>/WEB-INF/classes/jasperreports.properties` file. A restart of the application is required in this case.

Comment: I did as you wrote. Still there is no out put on report! How does Jasper know to get the created image and put it to the REPORT1 field?

Comment: When I use a text field instead of the image element, the value of the text field is null

Comment: Sorry, I've accidentally introduced a typo in the property key. I've edited my answer to correct this. This should fix the query executer registration. To answer your question in the first comment, I need to look at the DeployR Client code to tell. It is not JasperReports code(which is at the core of JasperSoft Studio).

Comment: I see no "net.sf.jasperreports.query.executer.factory" in libraries! there is a net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query package which has classes like AbstractQueryExecuterFactory

Comment: It is just a property that JasperReports looks for that needs to have that prefix(see the [config reference](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.query.executer.factory.{language})). It does not need to be a package

Comment: Any Idea how to get this done by using Extension registry? It does not work with the approach, you have declared.